Fundamental Group of Annulus Quotient
I was working on a problem from Lee's Introduction to Topological Manifolds and I am a bit confused as to what this space is supposed to look like. Here is what I am given:

Let $Q$ be the following annulus: $Q=\{z\in\mathbb{C} : 1\leq|z|\leq 3\}$. Let ~ be the equivalence relation on $Q$ generated by $z$~$-z$ if $z\in\partial Q$. Let $\bar{Q}=Q/$~, and let $q$ be the quotient map. Find a presentation for $\pi_1(\bar{Q},q(2))$, identifying specific loop(s) representing the generator(s).

I know what the annulus looks like and what I think it is saying is that we collapse all the boundary points to a single point. So is the realization of $\bar{Q}$ just an open band? I am having trouble visualizing this. Once I have this I know that I have to find open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $U\cap V$ is path connected and open, because then I can use the Seifert-Van Kampen theorem to compute the fundamental group (which I am guessing is gonna end up being the free group on one generator, or $\mathbb{Z}$). Any help would be appreciated.

It is definitely not saying that "we collapse all the boundary points to a single point." Read again. Also, even if this was the right interpretation, you would not get an "open band."

So we are identifying the antipodal points of the "inner" circle and the "outer" circle, but I am still confused as to what this looks. Are we getting a hollowed out sphere? Maybe some weird projective space type thing? I am a little lost.

Do you know what the Klein bottle is?

Yes, but I do not see how that factors in here. I know that the Klein bottle is obtained by gluing two Möbius bands along their boundary, but I do not see how any Möbius band appears here.

The wording of your last comment is odd, it seems to imply that you think the only description of a Klein bottle is by gluing two Möbius bands along their boundary. While that description may or may not be appropriate for your problem, there are certainly other descriptions of a Klein bottle.

I will answer your question regarding the identity of the quotient space $\bar Q$. Your remaining issues, regarding use of the Seifert Van Kampen theorem to compute the fundamental group, could perhaps be the topic of a separate post, in line with our guideline to ask one question per post.

One of the most famous tricks with a Möbius band $M$ constructed out of paper is to consider an embedded circle $C \subset M$ that goes exactly once around $M$, and then to take a scissors and cut $M$ along $C$. The result is an annulus $A$: the boundary circle of $M$ becomes one of the boundary circles of $A$; the other boundary circle of $A$ wraps twice around the the cut circle $C$.
One consequence of this trick is that if you go in the other direction --- starting with an annulus $A$, choosing one of the two boundary circles, and then forming a quotient space of $A$ by identifying antipodal points of the chosen boundary circle --- then the resulting quotient space is homeomorphic to the Möbius band. While it's not to hard to get a formal proof of this statement, I'll take this as given and I'll apply it to your problem.
Now let's consider your quotient map $Q \mapsto \bar Q$. Let's cut the annulus $Q = \{z \in \mathbb C : 1 \le |z| \le 3\}$ along its core circle $\gamma = \{z \in \mathbb C : |z|=2\}$, and similarly cut $\bar Q$ along the image $\bar\gamma \subset \bar Q$ of $\gamma$ under the quotient map $Q \mapsto \bar Q$. The result is a quotient map between disjoint unions of the form
$$Q_1 \sqcup Q_2 \mapsto \bar Q_1 \sqcup \bar Q_2
$$
such that $Q_1,Q_2$ are two annuli, and such that each of the two restrictions $Q_i \mapsto \bar Q_i$ is a quotient space which identifies antipodal points of one boundary circle of $Q_i$. It follows that each $\bar Q_i$ is a Möbius band. Also, letting $\gamma_i \subset Q_i$ be the boundary circle not involved in those identification, the boundary circle of $\bar Q_i$ is the image of $\gamma_i$, denoted $\bar\gamma_i$ under the quotient map $Q_i \mapsto \bar Q_i$.
Finally, your quotient space $\bar Q$ is homeomorphic to the quotient of the disjoint union $\bar Q_1 \sqcup \bar Q_2$ by identifying the boundary circle $\bar\gamma_1$ of the Möbius band $\bar Q_1$ with the boundary circle $\bar \gamma_2$ of the Möbius band $\bar Q_2$. So, as you say in your comment, $\bar Q$ is a Klein bottle.

Thank you so much. You have been a huge help!
